# Unable to generate tab hover using '.animate'

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the .animate function to change (and fade in/out) the background colour of my tabs when they're hovered over, returning to their original colour when the cursor is moved off the tab.

Here is my **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oroborous/q4fXm/)**.

I've attempted this off the back of being unable to find a clean solution using the .hover and/or .mouseover/mouseout functions, so a steer in the right direction would be most welcome.

Comment: Your fiddle worksforme. What exactly is your question?

Comment: That's interesting. Well, my question is why isn't it working basically, as I've got the plugin referenced in my HTML, it's a simple piece of code and the CSS is all there in the statement itself. EDIT:  Specifically, it's the fade that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you reference it AFTER you reference your jQuery?

Comment: I sure did, it's sitting directly beneath it.

Comment: Check my edit. It's really working with me, I have no clue what you did wrong...

Comment: Bizarre. Thanks for looking at it, I just wonder if the CSS is clashing (i.e. it's being over-ridden) with the function to change the background colour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `animate-colors` to your webpage (http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/). jQuery doesn't support color animation by default, but with this plugin you should be able to do whatever you want.

---

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/q4fXm/2/ Updated fiddle, with the plugin hardcoded inside the JS panel. I had to change the include on the left of the JSFiddle from MooTools to jQuery to make it work.

Comment: I had already referenced the plugin (valid for 1.8) immediately after the jQuery file reference. It's the fade that isn't happening!

Answer (score 0):

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the  [jQuery.Color() plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color) is used).

Comment: Well I've used the jQuery plugin you speak of, so I'm still out of ideas on how to realise the fade in/out.

Comment: use this plugin here is sample aslo http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the effects core (jquery.effects.core.js) for color animations to work. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects

Quoted from the above link: "The jQuery UI effects core extends the animate function to be able to animate colors as well."